# Странные "артефакты" на экране редактора при темной теме

Tags: mac, visual-studio-code

Mac 13" Siera 10.12.3

Заметил на всех темных темах такие артефакты

[image: Снимок экрана]

Была ли у кого-то подобная проблема?

Проблема исчезла когда сделал

`"window.zoomLevel": -1,`

Но при переходе мышкой с сайдбара на открытый файл - видно быстрое мелькание этих же белесых прямоугольников

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось эта ошибка не только у меня, и уже активно обсуждается сообществом и поднята в качестве issue на github. По комментариям это давняя ошибка хромиума c GPU растеризацией - [ссылка на issue chromiuma](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=633805)

Возможных решений несколько:

- Заменить цветовой профиль на "Color LCD"
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Командой `--force-gpu-rasterization`

Оба способа работают через раз и проблема всё еще открыта

Comment: Две ссылки оставлять не могу из-за нехватки репутации, вот кому интересно следить за данной проблемой ссылка на [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12473#issuecomment-284821595)